# why i am getting this Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method not implemented

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Why I am getting this exception while run the main class?

```
The data returned by Sort.sort is sorted.
Sort.sort took 0.5760083 seconds to read and sort the data.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method not implemented
    at Sort.threadedSort(Sort.java:21)
    at SortTest.main(SortTest.java:41)
C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.6\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.6\executor-snippets\run.xml:94: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

This is my `MergeSort` class

```java
public class MergeSort {

    // The mergeSort method returns a sorted copy of the
    // String objects contained in the String array data.
    /**
     * Sorts the String objects using the merge sort algorithm.
     * 
     * @param data the String objects to be sorted
     * @return the String objects sorted in ascending order
     */
    public static String[] mergeSort(String[] data) {
        if (data.length > 1) {
            String[] left = new String[data.length / 2];
            String[] right = new String[data.length - left.length];
            System.arraycopy(data, 0, left, 0, left.length);
            System.arraycopy(data, left.length, right, 0, right.length);
            left = mergeSort(left);
            right = mergeSort(right);
            return merge(left, right);
        }
        else {
            return data;
        }
    }

    /**
     * The merge method accepts two String arrays that are assumed
     * to be sorted in ascending order. The method will return a
     * sorted array of String objects containing all String objects
     * from the two input collections.
     * 
     * @param left a sorted collection of String objects
     * @param right a sorted collection of String objects
     * @return a sorted collection of String objects
     */
    public static String[] merge(String[] left, String[] right) {
        String[] data = new String[left.length + right.length];
        int lIndex = 0;
        int rIndex = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            if (lIndex == left.length) {
                data[i] = right[rIndex];
                rIndex++;
            }
            else if (rIndex == right.length) {
                data[i] = left[lIndex];
                lIndex++;
            }
            else if (left[lIndex].compareTo(right[rIndex]) < 0) {
                data[i] = left[lIndex];
                lIndex++;
            }
            else {
                data[i] = right[rIndex];
                rIndex++;
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

This is my `Sort` class.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Sort {

    /**
     * You are to implement this method. The method should invoke one or
     * more threads to read and sort the data from the collection of Files.
     * The method should return a sorted list of all of the String data 
     * contained in the files.
     * 
     * @param files
     * @return
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static String[] threadedSort(File[] files) throws IOException {
        throw new java.lang.IllegalStateException("Method not implemented");
    }

    /**
     * Given an array of files, this method will return a sorted 
     * list of the String data contained in each of the files.
     * 
     * @param files the files to be read
     * @return the sorted data
     * @throws IOException thrown if any errors occur reading the file
     */
    public static String[] sort(File[] files) throws IOException {
        String[] sortedData = new String[0];
        for (File file : files) {
            String[] data = getData(file);
            data = MergeSort.mergeSort(data);
            sortedData = MergeSort.merge(sortedData, data);
        }
        return sortedData;
    }

    /**
     * This method will read in the string data from the specified 
     * file and return the data as an array of String objects.
     * 
     * @param file the file containing the String data
     * @return String array containing the String data
     * @throws IOException thrown if any errors occur reading the file
     */
    private static String[] getData(File file) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        // Read the data from the file until the end of file is reached
        while (true) {
            String line = in.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                // the end of file was reached
                break;
            }
            else {
                data.add(line);
            }
        }
        //Close the input stream and return the data
        in.close();
        return data.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
}
```

This is my `SortTest` class:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * The class SortTest is used to test the threaded and non-threaded
 * sort methods. This program will call each method to sort the data
 * contained in the four test files. This program will then test the
 * results to ensure that the results are sorted in ascending order.
 * 
 * Simply run this program to verify that you have correctly implemented
 * the threaded sort method. The program will not verify if your sort
 * uses threads, but will verify if your implementation correctly 
 * sorted the data contained in the four files.
 * 
 * There should be no reason to make modifications to this class.
 */
public class SortTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File[] files = {new File("enable1.txt"),
                        new File("enable2k.txt"),
                        new File("lower.txt"),
                        new File("mixed.txt")};
        // Run Sort.sort on the files
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        String[] sortedData = Sort.sort(files);
        long stopTime = System.nanoTime();
        double elapsedTime = (stopTime - startTime) / 1000000000.0;

        // Test to ensure the data is sorted
        for (int i=0; i<sortedData.length-1; i++) {
            if (sortedData[i].compareTo(sortedData[i+1]) > 0) {
                System.out.println("The data returned by Sort.sort is not sorted.");
                throw new java.lang.IllegalStateException("The data returned by Sort.sort is not sorted");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The data returned by Sort.sort is sorted.");
        System.out.println("Sort.sort took " + elapsedTime + " seconds to read and sort the data.");

        // Run Sort.threadedSort on the files and test to ensure the data is sorted
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        String[] threadSortedData = Sort.threadedSort(files);
        stopTime = System.nanoTime();
        double threadedElapsedTime = (stopTime - startTime)/ 1000000000.0;

        // Test to ensure the data is sorted
        if (sortedData.length != threadSortedData.length) {
            System.out.println("The data return by Sort.threadedSort is missing data");
            throw new java.lang.IllegalStateException("The data returned by Sort.threadedSort is not sorted");
        }
        for (int i=0; i<threadSortedData.length-1; i++) {
            if (threadSortedData[i].compareTo(threadSortedData[i+1]) > 0) {
                System.out.println("The data return by Sort.threadedSort is not sorted");
                throw new java.lang.IllegalStateException("The data returned by Sort.threadedSort is not sorted");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The data returned by Sort.threadedSort is sorted.");
        System.out.println("Sort.threadedSort took " + threadedElapsedTime + " seconds to read and sort the data.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your test is invoking Sort.threadedSort(..).  That method is implemented to throw the exception you have shown.  You have to replace that exception-throwing with an actual implementation.

Answer (score 1):

From your own post:

```
public class Sort {

   /**
          * You are to implement this method. The method should invoke one or
       * more threads to read and sort the data from the collection of Files.
         * The method should return a sorted list of all of the String data 
       * contained in the files.
            * 
       * @param files
        * @return
        * @throws IOException 
               */
         public static String[] threadedSort(File[] files) throws IOException {
          throw new java.lang.IllegalStateException("Method not implemented");
           }
```

That's the exception that you're seeing, and it's there because you didn't do what the comment told you to do yet.

Comment: i read the comment but not getting please

Comment: You need to remove that line and replace it with actual code that does what the comment says.

Comment: @BharatChaudhari you are asking the wrong question. What you actually want help with is how to implement method `threadedSort`. I think you need to write a method similar to method `sort` (in class `Sort`) but in each loop iteration, launch a separate `Thread` that performs the merge sort. Then combine all the sorted files. Consider editing your question.